# How can I use cli Go files that belong to a web app?

Tags: go

My question is related to the structure or approach of Go applications. I have got the following application.

```
root
  |- app
  | |- services
  | |- repositories
  | |- handlers
  | |- commands
  |- go.mod
  |- main.go
```

The Go files in the commands package are working independently. The rest of the packages are working for a web application. I start an HTTP web server in the main.go

So, I'd like to run the Go files in the commands packages in the crontab. But as I know, I'll build these whole packages into a single binary file. My question is how can I run the Go files in the commands packages independently in the crontab? I think I should separate them into 2 applications such as "web app" and "command app" but actually they are related to each other and I don't want to manage 2 apps differently. May I use commands Go files in the crontab and on the other hand start an HTTP web server in the main.go?

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't have multiple `main` packages in a single project as long as each one is in a separate directory. If you have encountered an issue while trying to execute the cli programs, launched by crontab, alongside you web app then you should describe that problem.

Comment: In this case, should I build them separately? So, do I have multiple binary files that can I run them independently?

Comment: Yes, each `main` package is a separate program. `main` packages cannot be imported and reused by other packages.

Comment: Note that when building multiple `main` packages using a single `go build` command you MUST specify the output directory with the `-o` flag, otherwise: *"build compiles the packages but discards the resulting object, serving only as a check that the packages can be built."* https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll keep them in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't import packages from your web application module into another one, but if you want to keep them together, you can just do what is quite common, and add additional `main` packages in specific directories, giving a directory structure like this:

```
root
  |- app
  |  |-services
  |  |-...
  |- cmd
  |   |- tools
  |   |   |- main.go
  |- main.go
```

You can build/install your CLI binary simply by running `go build ./cmd/tools` or `go install ./cmd/tools`

Comment: So they will work as different apps but they will stand in the same root directory, right? As a result, I'll get 2 different binary files, won't I?
for a web app and for a command app

Comment: Yes, they'll compile to 2 separate binaries (I just gave the `go build ./cmd/tools` command as an example of how you can compile/install that specific binary, but the code would be in a single module (root directory), and compile to 2 distinct binaries.

Comment: yes, I can do it however I was wondering is it a good idea or way? Does the community handle this case in this way?

Comment: @MertSimsek Having a `cmd` directory in a project, and building several binaries from a single repository is very common. There's even examples in [golang's own repositories](https://github.com/golang/tools) that do this. Equally common is to have `cmd subcommand` where your webserver would be started by running `foo web` and the CLI tools would be going through `foo tools`, much like `go build`, `go install`, and `go test` work